# after row.add in DataTable not showing responsive

Tags: javascript, datatable, responsive

I have the table .

```
var mytable=$('#my-table').DataTable({options});
```

when generated tag table is ...

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive dataTable no-footer" id="my-table" role="grid" aria-describedby="my-table_info">
```

I add row with `mytable.row.add({columns});` 
when I added new row ,table not showing responsive in Firefox browser(in chrome is showed responsive when remove class `'datatable'` from tag table).

If that is empty is displayed correctly.

why show the table responsive?

best regard.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<div class="table-responsive">` div before your table. And remove, if there are any `width="100%"` style applied to your table.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I do it.but show me scroll vertical and horizontal and The table is still wide but not out of page.

Comment: Can you please create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? It is hard to tell without a live code.

Comment: I can't.not load js file.there are complex.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is about a `width="100%"` style applied somewhere in your code but without a live code it is impossible to tell exactly.

Answer (score 0):

solved .

I add

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "autoWidth": false
} );
```

worked in chrome.

and set width for column by CSS .that's worked in firefox.

That reason is column auto width giving value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
dataTable.columns.adjust().draw()
```

Worked for me.